# Why I can't select an element of this matrix

Tags: r

I want to extract elements from the matrix "wttidy" that you can see in the following picture:

[Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIH8A.png)

I also have a datatable where I have the indices needed for the matrix wttidy. The row index is the column "arrivals$letterindex" and the column index is the column "arrivals$nextvalue". I'm noob to R so my first thought was do something like `arrivals$result<- wttidy[arrivals$letterindex, arrivals$nextvalue]` but for each element.

I cannot use for loops so I have written two funcions.

```
funcc <- function(x){
  B<- as.numeric(arrivals$letterindex[x+1])
  return(B)
}
arrivals$nextvalue<- as.numeric(lapply(1:nrow(arrivals), funcc))
value<- wttidy[arrivals$letterindex, ]

funx <- function(x){
  rowvalue<- data.table(value[x, ])
  A<-  as.numeric(arrivals$nextvalue[x])
  dist<- rowvalue[, A]
  return(dist)
}
arrivals$result<- lapply(1:nrow(arrivals), funx)
```

This only returns the first column of the row needed of the matrix `wttidy` but I don't understand why it doesn't return the column that I need.

Here you have the results of the code and you can see it only extracts the first column.

[Return of "arrivals"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4GaN.png)

Comment: In `funx` remove the call to `data.table`.

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the code you've tried and with the output of `dput(wttidy)`and the output of `dput(arrivals)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(arrivals, 20))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
wttidy = array(c(100, 80, 80, 60, 60, 60,
                 100, 100, 80, 80, 60, 60,
                 120, 100, 80, 80, 80, 60,
                 140, 100, 80, 80, 80, 60,
                 160, 120, 100, 100, 80, 60,
                 180, 140, 120, 120, 100, 80),
               dim =c(6,6))

dimnames(wttidy)[[2]] = LETTERS[1:6]

fwttidy = function(i, j) wttidy[i,j]
fwttidy = Vectorize(fwttidy)

n=100
df = tibble(
  letterindex = sample(1:6, n, replace = TRUE),
  nextvalue = sample(LETTERS[1:6], n, replace = TRUE)
) %>% mutate(
  result = fwttidy(letterindex, nextvalue)
)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 100 x 3
   letterindex nextvalue result
         <int> <chr>      <dbl>
 1           1 E            160
 2           6 A             60
 3           1 C            120
 4           4 B             80
 5           5 F            100
 6           6 D             60
 7           1 D            140
 8           6 C             60
 9           3 D             80
10           3 B             80
# ... with 90 more rows
```